# our www.ourdomain.com, managed by Route53 is not resolving to https

Tags: https, amazon-route53

we are using route53 to manage our domain, however our www.ourdomain.com is not resolving to https.

1) Currently, we have an AWS Classic Loadbalancer with an certificate installed so that we can serve the following domains:
admin.ourdomain.com

2) The certificate we created with AWS Certificate Manager, has registered www.ourdomain.com, and ourdomain.com, as well as admin.ourdomain.com.  All have been set up successfully.

3) In Route53, our admin.ourdomain.com has an A record pointing to the ALIAS of our loadbalancer.

4) In Route53 www.ourdomain.com has an A record pointing to two external IP Addresses which are firebase servers hosting our mobile app.

www.ourdomain.com is NOT resolving to https.  What must we do to have them resolve to hTTPS?

Comment: DNS servers resolve a domain name to an IP address. This has nothing to do with protocols being used to communicate with the destination servers. You can test the DNS resolution by using `ping` or `dnslookup` to display the resolved IP address. Does the correct IP address appear?

Comment: If you go straight to the firebase servers via IP address rather than domain name, does HTTPS work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I actually had to wander over to Firebase, login, and click on hosting.  I then pressed "Add a domain" and added www.ourdomain.com.
It then asked me to verify the domain with a TXT record, which I added to Route53.
It then verified after waiting a bit.  After this, Route53 asked me to add two A records .. which I did... after about 1 hour, our domain resolved properly to https